# What should be done with obsolete answers about misprints?

Tags: discussion

1. The question was asked.
2. There were some misprints in its code, so that shown code couldn't work at all.
3. Of course it got some answers about misprints.
4. After that a correct answer is posted.
5. Author of the question edits the question to fix misprints.
6. Answers about misprints are now obsolete and useless.

I thought that answers about misprints (3) should be deleted. But what if they aren't? Should I flag them? If yes, how?

> Should the question be closed?

No, it's not about misprint or nonreprodusable problem. It contains the real problem, moreover the solution for this problem is given in answer (4).

> Should the answer from (3) be flagged as Not an answer?

Seems like no, as there was an attempt to answer the question. But it become obsolete.

> Should the answer from (3) be flagged as Very low quality?

Maybe, but separately from the question they are correct. Also, according to meta this flag shouldn't be used for technical issues.

**So, what should be done with such answers?**

Example: [innerHTML update value but HTML rendering isn't changed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39570582/4928642)

Comment: I agree that it is not a NAA, and there is plenty of support for that idea (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer). I consider any non-spam, non-abusive, and non-link-only answer that makes any attempt, no matter how ineffectual, incompetent, or misled, to answer the question to be a legitimate answer that should not be flagged, and should be marked "looks ok" if seen in the VLQ review queue. Incorrect answers deserve downvotes - please downvote factually incorrect answers liberally, to help others recognize them as incorrect!

Comment: It's probably more the questions fault. We don't appreciate this kind of moving targets asking stuff beyond providing a [MCVE] in 1st place. Also the answers should have been comments probably.

Comment: but after the question is edited, the context looks as if NAA for me

Answer (score 5):

Downvote the answers - they're not useful.

You left an answer that fixed the problem, and that (and any other useful answers) should float to the top for future visitors. After you downvote, it's up to those users to delete them *(or someone with enough rep can vote to delete).*

If you're feeling generous, leave a comment clarifying why (as you did) but you're not required to do so. The answers *are* answers, but they're obsolete. Unfortunately, there's no 'obsolete' close reason.

Hopefully in the future, they'll learn to point out such typos in a comment and, when it ends up the problem *is* just a syntax error, vote to close the question as a "simple typographical error".

Comment: I think it is unfair to downvote answers wich were trying to help. They are not bad or totally incorrect, they are obsolete just...

Comment: @Qwertiy I vote on an answer's content, not the author's intent. If the content is wrong or not useful, I'm going to downvote. That's not unfair, because downvoting *is not something bad*. To me, it is an obligation, in order to keep the quality of answers (and questions) on Stack Overflow high.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, if the answer is originally wrong or useless it would be right to downwote. But if it became useless dew to question edit, I see no reasons to downvote it. It's a problem of question, not the problem of answer, then why to downvote answer?

Comment: @Qwertiy I'm not going to research the history of the question and its answers every time I vote. I'm going to look at the question as it is presented to me, vote (or not) based on its contents. Same for the answers. If the authors of these posts don't want the downvotes, they are free to edit or delete their answers (or questions). I *might* leave a comment indicating why I think my downvote was warranted.  I *might* even go back to the posts to see if they've been updated, especially if I vote early on in the lifetime of the post, and it was an interesting post.